# How to handle multi-machine-dot-file-versioning

Tags: git, dot-files

I'm thinking about versioning my dot-files via git on a public repository. I've moved all the interesting dot-files like .profiles or .vimrc to the repository and subsequently symlinked them to there origin places.

Now, some of my dot-files contains very machine dependant stuff like for example my fluxbox-keys-file where I've defined shortcuts for my notebook-keyboard which is different from my desktop-keyboard. How should I handle with those files? Holding a single branch for every machine?

Comment: I suggest the same reference I suggested in your other question, https://dotfiles.github.io/, which includes links to tools that will handle host-specific files for you.

Comment: A branch per machine?